simplify tacit fork definition
I have the following tacit fork (intended to be used monadically):
F&.I G H&.I
i.e. the left and right verbs F and H of the fork get I applied with &. (under) before feeding the outputs to G.
Is there a way to simplify the fork definition, in the sense that &.I is only specified once?
(F G H)&.I is not equivalent since I^:_1 is applied after G, not before.
(F G&(I^:_1) H)@I is equivalent but clearly not simpler/conciser.

I'd say you won't get more clear/concise than what you have.
The only immediate simplification I see would be to define &.I as an adverb and use that instead.
